# Looping over two arrays for each row in a table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nested-loops, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following set of json

```
[
    {
        "drink_name": "Ananascocktail",
        "ingredients": [
            "Ananas",
            "Färskpressad limesaft",
            "Apelsinjuice",
            "Farinsocker",
            "Rom"
        ],
        "alternatives": [
            "",
            "Limesaft",
            "",
            "Socker",
            null
        ]
    },
    {
        "drink_name": "Blå Pilthammer",
        "ingredients": [
            "Blåbärsvodka",
            "Apelsinjuice",
            "Bonaqua Citron"
        ],
        "alternatives": [
            "Vodka",
            "",
            ""
        ]
    }
]
```

How do I loop over the `ingredients` and `alternatives` to place each element in separate `<td>`'s on the same `<tr>`?

I've tried putting a `ng-repeat` on the row, but that makes a new row for each element.
I must, however, use a `ng-repeat` on the `<tr>` since I have multiple ingredients/alternatives.

I've googled around for over an hour but can't find anything that quite fit my needs.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by doing the following

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="ingredient in json.ingredients">
    <td>{{ingredient}}</td>
      <td ng-repeat="alternative in json.alternatives track by $index" ng-if="$parent.$index === $index">{{alternative}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

I only allow `alternatives` to place a `<td>` if its `$index` is the same as its `$parent`'s `$index`. Why that solved it is beyond me